# Issue storing data to SQL DB

Tags: php, sql, forms

I am trying to store some form data to a SQL database using the following query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO attendees (first_name, surname, partner, phone) VALUES ($first_name, $surname, $partner, $phone)";
```

It works perfectly if I hard code the values to test it, but when using these variables, it breaks and gives me **Error 1054**

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$surname    = $_POST['surname'];
$partner    = $_POST['partner'];
$phone  = $_POST['phone'];
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: you do not quote variables, try to add quotes to all your variables

Comment: Do you use the super-deprecated functions like `mysql_*`? Then if you do you might want to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function also and quotes :)

Comment: try to use [PHP Prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO attendees (first_name, surname, partner, phone) VALUES ($first_name, $surname, $partner, $phone)";
```

should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO attendees (first_name, surname, partner, phone) VALUES ('$first_name', '$surname', '$partner', '$phone')";
```

you are missing quotes around field content.

Warning: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

try to use [PHP Prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement . Or at-least use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: This solution is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please either fix that or at least mention it.

Comment: @Bluewind thanks for pointing out. don't know how i missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Err 1054 means that you are using a column name that doesn't exist.

In this case, as there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your insert statement (assuming that all the variables have data in them) it means you have likely typo'ed a column name.

On second thoughts, you probably need single quotes around the strings, but the first part of my answer still stands.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, stop using mysql_ functions and look for PDO and prepared statements: if you'll do as suggested, this problem will sort by itself.

Anyway, the problem is that the query will replace the values with the strings contained in your `$_POST` array... but without string delimiters.

This means that mysql will look at them as column names, and spaces will break them!

solution:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO attendees (first_name, surname, partner, phone) VALUES ('$first_name', '$surname', '$partner', '$phone')";
```

NOTICE that this will leave you wide open to SQL injection attacks!

with PDO it'll look something similar to this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO attendees (first_name, surname, partner, phone) VALUES (:fname, :sname, :partn, :phone)");
$stmt->execute(array(':fname' => $first_name, ':sname' => $surname_name, [the others]))
```

which will is much more secure and plainly better all around.

Answer (score 0):

Please escape and verify your inputs, otherwise you'll be vulnerable to SQL injections.

Here's a list of good solutions on how to do that: http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Basically try to use prepared statements if possible, otherwise use `mysql_real_escape_string()`